# Response Header has 2 set-cookie (AWSALB and AWSALBCORS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cookies, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

In my application, I added secure cookies and I deployed it to the remote server. However, when I do a request, I can see that there are 2 identical cookies (1 is AWSALB unsecure, 2 is AWSALBCORS secure):

```
set-cookie
    AWSALB=J8Hw07Jy8ein8Hei2SOME_NUMBERSMiRhCvCtL+1psSOME_NUMBERS84qI2vb/lmSOME_NUMBERS61i/LWSOME_NUMBERSLK2/itJs7pSOME_NUMBERSqcE8Y2/D3C55sSOME_NUMBERSGQUzxBh; Expires=Fri, 15 Jan 2021 07:19:43 GMT; Path=/
set-cookie
    AWSALBCORS=J8Hw07Jy8ein8Hei2SOME_NUMBERSMiRhCvCtL+1psSOME_NUMBERS84qI2vb/lmSOME_NUMBERS61i/LWSOME_NUMBERSLK2/itJs7pSOME_NUMBERSqcE8Y2/D3C55sSOME_NUMBERSGQUzxBh; Expires=Fri, 15 Jan 2021 07:19:43 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
```

I investigated it and found out that it is related to AWS Load balancer, but I am unable to further investigate. I do not want to see unsecure cookie in response header. How can I remove it? Where should I look into?

Comment: *"I do not want to see unsecure cookie in response header"* - why? Do you actually use an ALB in your infrastructure? Do you have stickiness enabled?

Comment: @luk2302 I would like to have better security (secure cookie). If I have unsecure cookie (AWSALB), doesn't it mean I have less secure application? I also checked load balancers and their target groups have stickiness enabled.

Comment: Did you find a way to edit those headers? I'm in a similar situation and need to add HttpOnly on both headers (AWSALB and AWSALBCORS) @mqg38001